# Docker-Compose for react and flask execute the containers with docker-compose up

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

I use docker-compose to build my flask and react images, but when I run the docker-compose command, my flask container is up but my react container is not activated, and to activate it I ran the command run image, I don't have idea why this happens, I hope you can explain why.

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  cloud-flask-back:
    container_name: flask
    build: ./Flask
    ports:
        - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
        - ./Flask:/cloud
    environment:
      FLASK_ENV: development
    restart: on-failure
  cloud-react-front:
    container_name: react
    build: ./cloud-front
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./cloud-front:/cloud-front-end
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      PORT: 3000
    restart: on-failure
```

my Dockerfile for react

```
FROM node:14
# Create app directory
WORKDIR /cloud-front-end
# Install app dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# Copy app source code
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks for reading

Comment: What error do you get?  The `volumes:` directive overwrites basically everything the Dockerfile you show does (and if you're not on a native-Linux host, will overwrite the image's `node_modules` directory with a wrong-architecture tree); does deleting that help?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue before while trying to run react app container using 'node' image. I believe the conatiner starts and stops when we try to ru docker-compose.

Please try adding **"stdin_open: true"** to the 'cloud-react-front' service in docker-compose.yml. This worked for me.

Comment: Do I have to remove the development environment (NODE_ENV: development) variable?

Comment: I don't think you need to remove the environment variable. stdin_open: true will lock the shell to interactive mode with the react app container. Without this the container automatically stops.

Answer (score 0):

Attached volumes in cloud-react-front will override all files in container with host volumes, so there are no node_modules available for the container.

I am assuming you are running this setup in development.
try running: `docker-compose run cloud-react-front npm install` it will add node_modules to your host

and then try: `docker-compose up`, it should work.